# How do I use built-in extract feature in Windows explorer from the command line?

Tags: windows, batch, command-line

How do I use built-in extract feature in Windows explorer from the command line?

I can't install any third party compression tools such as WinZIP, WinRAR or 7Zip.

I just need this to work on Windows 2003 and later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First if you wanted to use 7Zip you could run 7za which is a stand-alone version of 7z.

Also, here is a similar question, that this answer may help you.
https://serverfault.com/questions/39071/does-windows-have-a-built-in-zip-command-for-the-command-line

I have a similar situation and I usually install simple apps on one machine and copy the program files directory it makes to a flash drive.  For simple self contained apps, it will work.  You don't get any of the Explorer right-click integration, but the app works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Scott...finally got back to looking at this problem again. That link was handy because this answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/39071/does-windows-have-a-built-in-zip-command-for-the-command-line/39243#39243 lead to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/daiken/archive/2007/02/12/compress-files-with-windows-powershell-then-package-a-windows-vista-sidebar-gadget.aspx and we can use PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use Powershell v3+

```
Expand-Archive "Zip path" "Destination"
```